# Validating Number Step Counts In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, math, numbers

How do you validate a number to ensure it falls in the proper step? I know this can be done with HTML with the *step* attribute. How do you do this only using JavaScript for validation on the step intervals. Here is my script and it works most of the time. I made the same script in PHP and I have no issues at all.

To my understanding JavaScript has a math issues when you work with decimal numbers and can cause number to not be exact and in this situation I need the math to return with the exact correct numbers since the math formula I am using detects if the step intervals are valid by weather the math returns a integer or a float number.

The *input HTML tag* has a built-in step validation and for example -44.667 is a valid step interval.

Is there a better way to do this in JS and PHP?

```
<input type="number" min="-45" step="0.333" value="-45">

<script>

var number = -44.667
var step = 0.333;
var min = -45;



//Detects if min is 0 or less
if (min <= 0) {
    var stepNumber = number + Math.abs(min);
}

else {
    var stepNumber = number - min;
}



//This will see if the steps intervals are valid in the number. If stepMultiplier is a integer number, it is valid. If it is a float number, it is not valid.
var stepMultiplier = stepNumber / step;


//Detect if the number is a float number
if (stepMultiplier % 1 !== 0) {
    console.error('Step invalid');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const number = -44.667
const step = 0.333
const min = -45

function isInRange(number, { max, min, step } = {}) {
  if (max && max < number) return false
  if (min && min > number) return false
  if (step) {
    const tempNumber = number - min
    if (tempNumber.toPrecision(12) % step !== 0) return false
  }
  return true
}

console.log(isInRange(number, { min, step }))
```

Note that the toPrecision is required to handle floating point error issues. Let me know if there's a more elegant solution to fixing that.

Comment: This will not work if number is -44.001. It seems no matter what one does, it will not work 100% of the time.

Comment: How about instead of comparing to 0 we check if it's greater than 1e-10? Not super elegant but I would assume it would work for any step that isn't incredibly small.

Comment: `if (tempNumber % step > 1e-10) return false`

Comment: Sadly I get the same results either way.